# How to solve a VCG auction game?

Tags: game-theory, utility, auction-theory

So i have this question:[image]

And these are the 5 highest marginal valuations according to the answer sheet:
[image]

This is how the answer sheet defines the vcg mechanism
[image]

How is the answer sheet chosing these 5 highest marginal valuations? Why are they 5? Why are they the numbers that they are ? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why there's $5$. I would think that's up to your author. It seems he just picked the highest marginal valuations in order. The sixth highest marginal valuation for example would be $70 \to $ P1. Then $70 \to $ P5 etcetera.

Comment: But then why isn't it written that 70 is p1 ecc?

Comment: On what basis do i decide which are the highest values?

Comment: I was thinking of going by rows but it doesn't make sense

Comment: The five values he listed are the literal highest values in the table. No need to consider rows or columns.

Comment: Well then why isn't 70 in the values? or 75?

Comment: Maybe he choose 5 because there are 5 items?

Comment: please check my edit. it says that for a vcg mechanism i need to assign n items according to the n highest marginal valuations... is this it?

Comment: Then there is your answer. This is a $5$-item auction, so he chooses the $5$-highest valuations.